# show css icon with select icon class selcetbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In my form select box have some icon class and i want that when user select a class from list box then it show another div.

i write a code but cant know how to append css

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#ion").change(function() {
     $(".icon-preview").empty();
     if ( $("#icon").val()!="" ){
        $(".icon-preview").append("");
     }
     else{
        $(".icon-preview").append("displays icon here");
     }
   });
 });
</script>

<div class="icon-preview"></div>
```

my select box

```
<select multiple class="form-control" id="icon"  name="icon">
                  <option value="icon-home-2">icon-home-2</option>
                  <option value="icon-mobile">icon-mobile</option>

</select>
```

my output will be like

```
<div class="icon-preview">
    <i class="icon-mobile"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: You have typo: change `$("#ion")` to `$("#icon")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#icon").change(function() {
     $(".icon-preview").empty();
     if ( $("#icon").val()!="" ){
        $(".icon-preview").append('<i class="'+$(this).val()+'">test</i>');
     }
   });
 });
```

There were few problems:

- You have type: `$("#ion")` to `$("#icon")`.
- You should append class `if($("#icon").val()!="")` instead of `if($("#icon").val()=="")`

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/beNbm/)</kbd>

Comment: +1 Never post an answer as a comment (and vice-versa) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this. There are some typo errors in your code. check that too..

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#icon").change(function() {
     $(".icon-preview").empty();
     if ( $(this).val()!="" ){
        $(".icon-preview").append("");
     }
     else{
        $(".icon-preview").append('<i class="'+$(this).val()+'"></i>');
     }
   });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Did you change $('#ion') to $('#icon') in your code?